Why youtube don't need user to interact first with document for playing a video?
I am creating a VOD website, and when working on the deep url functionality (url that point directly a video ex: mysite.com/watch/abcd) i have this error in console (Chrome):
videoplayer.js:149 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay
I completly understand the problem, but how does youtube make it work?
When you open a direct link, the video launch itself: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
(I tried with autoplay but same error)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#autoplay_availability See also How does Youtube autoplay its videos?

@MatthieuCharbonnier Autoplay should work if you set muted to true in your video element settings. If your users are going to direct page links (not clicking) then that page must have text saying "click or tap to hear audio" (where you add a clickable but transparent element above the video object). The click/tap handling function will then un-mute.  PS: "above" means use CSS layering with z-index etc...
